# Error message while trying to make a shopping cart

Tags: php, shopping-cart

The following code is not my own. I'm trying to learn how to make a shopping cart but i'm stuck on this part of the tutorial. Please verify the code and tell me what i'm doing wrong.

This is products.php:

```
if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=="add"){

 $id=intval($_GET['id']);

if(isset($_SESSION['cart'][$id])){
  $_SESSION['cart'][$id]['quantity']++;

}else{

 $query_s=mysql_query($sql_s);
    $row_s=mysql_fetch_array($query_s);
     $_SESSION['cart'][$row_s'id_product']]=array(
        "quantity" => 1,
        "price" => $row_s['price']
       );


}

}

?>

<h1>Product List</h1>
<?php 

echo print_r($_SESSION['cart']);
?>

<table>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>

<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY name ASC";
$query = mysql_query($sql);

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
?>
<tr>
   <td><?php echo $row['name'] ?> </td>
   <td><?php echo $row['description'] ?> </td>
   <td><?php echo $row['price'] ?>$</td>
   <td><a href="index.php?page=products&action=add&id=<?php echo $row['id_product']>">Add to cart</a></td>
   </tr>

<?php

}

?>

</table>
```

This is index.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
include("connection.php");

if(isset($_GET['page']))
{

$pages=array("products","cart");

if(in_array($_GET['page'], $pages)) {

$_page=$_GET['page'];

}else{

$_page="products";

}

} 

else {

$_page="products";

}


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<title>Shopping cart</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">

<div id="main">

<?php require($_page.".php"); ?>


</div> <!--end of main-->

<div id="sidebar">

</div> <!--end of sidebar-->
</div> <!--end of container-->

</body>
</html>
```

This is the css file style.css:

```
a { 
color: #48577D;
text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover{
text-decoration:underline;
}

body {
font-family: Verdana;
font-size: 12px;
color: #444;
}

h1, h2 { margin-bottom: 15px;}

h1 { font-size:18px;}
h2 {font-size: 16px;}

#container {
width:700px;
margin: 150px auto;
background-color:#eee;
padding:15px;
overflow:hidden;
}

#main {
width: 490px;
float: left;
}

#main table {
width: 480px;
}

  #main table th {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #48577D;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  }


  #main table td {
  padding: 5px;
}

#sidebar {
width: 200px;
float: left;
}
```

This is the connection.php:

```
<?php

$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");


$database=mysql_select_db('tutorials');

?>
```

This is cart.php:

```
This is your cart
```

It's not incrementing the values properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error here:

```
$_SESSION['cart'][$row_s'id_product']]
```

I think it's supposed to be:

```
$_SESSION['cart'][$row_s['id_product']]
```

---

You will easily catch these errors if you turn on error reporting. There is no reason to not have it turned on in development.